# most optimal sql query for a simple table design

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to come up with the most optimal query to solve this problem.

I have simple table made up of columns name(string) and organization_id(int). This table contains a list of names that belong to one or more organizations.

How can I get a list of all the names that belong to the organizations that both "Jim" and "Andy" belong to?

Example:

```
- John,1
- Jim,1
- Jim,2
- Andy,2
- Carl,2
- Jim,3
- Carl,3
- Andy,4
- John,4
- Jim,5
- Randy,5
- Andy,5
```

So the query should return to me `Jim,2|Andy,2|Carl,2|Jim,5|Randy,5|Andy,5`  as both Jim and Andy belong to organizations 2 and 5.

Any ideas?

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight forward `JOIN` should do it;

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.name 
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.organization_id = t2.organization_id AND t2.name = 'Jim'
JOIN Table1 t3 ON t1.organization_id = t3.organization_id AND t3.name = 'Andy'
ORDER BY t1.name
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/088ff8/5).

EDIT: [An Oracle SQLfiddle with the same query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84cf7/2).

Answer (score 1):

To get the organizations that "Jim" and "Andy" belong to, I like to use aggregation:

```
select organization
from t
group by organization
having sum(case when name = 'Jim' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when name = 'Andy' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

You can then get all the people in these organizations using:

```
select *
from t
where organization in (select organization
                       from t
                       group by organization
                       having sum(case when name = 'Jim' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                              sum(case when name = 'Andy' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
                      )
```